# How to show Collection data in VS WPF Design panel?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

**How do I get VS to populate my `ListView` with sample data in the Design panel?**

I'm stumped. I've done a fair bit of reading and googling and can't find a solid answer. Showing fake data in the VS Design panel would greatly speed up theming as I wouldn't have to debug it every few changes.

Here is my code:

**XAML:**

```
<ListView DataContext="{Binding}"
          Name="PeopleListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Person">
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstNameView}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastNameView}" />
                </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**COLLECTION:**

```
public class People : ObservableCollection<Person>
{
    public People()
    {
        this.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        this.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        this.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
    }
}
```

**MAIN:**

```
private People PList;

public MainWindow()
{
    this.PList = new People();
    PeopleListView.ItemsSource = this.PList;
}
```

**EDIT & PROGRESS:**

I read through the tutorials found in the link provided by *Matt West*. They were very helpful. I almost got this figured out.

I ran into a problem when the Designer tries to display the Sample Data. I get this error on my sample properties: `Writable property or collection expected`. I understand the error, I just don't know how to fix it without giving each property a `set` statement.

Here is my code:

**Person Class:**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _LastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this._email; }
        set
        {
            this._FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstNameView");
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return this._password; }
        set
        {
            this._LastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstNameView");
        }
    }
    public string FirstNameView
    {
        get { return this.FirstName; }
    }
    public string LastNameView
    {
        get { return this.LastName; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) { /*...*/ }
}
```

**PeopleViewSampleData.xaml:**

```
<sample:People xmlns:sample="clr-namespace:MyProgram">
    <sample:Person FirstNameView="John" LastNameView="Doe" />
</sample:People>
```

**EDIT, SOLUTION:**
Having `ItemSource`, `DataContext`, and `:DataContext` setup as follows made it work. If any of that was missing,  nothing would show.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DataContext="{Binding}"
          d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/SampleData/PeopleListViewSampleData.xaml}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to set DataContext on the people list view AND set the ItemsSource. Get rid of the DataContext={Binding}. Not sure if this will solve your Design problem or not. In general its usually a good idea to use the d:DesignData and d:DesignInstance properties for this though. Here is a tutorial:
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/

Comment: How do I get that to resolve? I get these errors `The property 'DataContext' was not found in type 'ListView'.`, `Cannot resolve symbol 'd'`, `Cannot resolve symbol 'DataContext'`... with this code: `<ListView d:DataContext="....."`

Comment: @PiZzL3: You should read the other article linked on the one above: http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/visual-studio-2010-beta2-sample-data-project-templates/   This explains how to add the `d:` namespace

Comment: Thanks for the second link, sadly this doesn't work. It won't show the data in the `ListView` unless I Debug..

Comment: I found a more up to date link in the article's comments: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/sample-data-in-the-wpf-and-silverlight-designer.aspx . I'll be trying that asap.

Comment: The msdn article helped a lot. I almost have this worked out. The only problem is in my `SampleData.xaml` file, `<sample:Person FirstName="John"` gives me a `Writable property or collection expected`. This causes `FirstName` not to show in the Designer. I can't change it to a writable property because I display it only using `get` with formatting rules.

Comment: I finally got this to work with the following article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/08/27/designdata-mvvm-support-in-blend-vs2010-and-wpf-silverlight.aspx. Thanks for all the help!